# Graphic elements displayed incorrectly after upgrade to Xubuntu 18.04.2 LTS

Tags: upgrade, xubuntu, thunderbird, gtk3, lightning

Just did upgrade Xubuntu 16.04 LTS  to 18.04.2 LTS with help from a friend via terminal; 
my reason was to be able to use my updated LinHabu 19 (accounting software) which needs at least 16.01 and was changed to GTK+ 3. 
Now everything is up and running, the programme is functional, but the menu buttons and the graphic lineout are not displayed correctly. In the documentary of LinHabu is said this can happen, but it does not specify the exact package. it just says oxygen-gtk would not work correctly and where you find settings in KDE and i do not know where to start really...

Same case in the Lighning calendar i use with Thunderbird. Everything works, but editing menues are missing lines and it looks all weird.

How could i find out which theme i am working with and which one i should? And how do i have to implement it? If somebody could help just telling me command lines, i probably will get along; so far i never did any compiling or configuring themes because i do not care about the visual so much, as long as thing are functioning,but this is a bit much.
Thank you very much for suggestions!

[image: screenshot calendar date edit window]
[image: popup on starting LinHabu]

Comment: Please, attach screenshots of various problems you see, this may give some ideas *(in case it's not a theme issue; this explanation sounds a little bit odd to me)*. But to answer your direct question: you can use `lxappearance` app to configure currently loaded GTK theme.

Comment: Thank you Hi-Angel, will try to attach screenshots, but am not allowed to add pics to my post...hmmm. I never configured GTK themes before i must admit. Therefore I am lost a bit. One of my Linux friends told me today i should try installing gtk-breeze package. Could you agree to that?

Comment: gtk-breeze is just one of many themes out there. Sounds okay, why not. FWIW, I'm personally using gtk-breeze. And while on it: as I have a bit more reputation, I made your screenshot visible. I think I might see what you mean, yeah, that indeed looks like a theme issue.

Comment: Thank you very much, have to stop now, but get back to it soon, need some tutoringe here, probably back Monday!

Answer (score 0):

Try Settings -> Appearence and pick another gtk theme. If you wish, you can try changing your titlebar theme to match your new theme in Settings -> Window Manager.